# Analyze Windows 10 Kernel Dump for Hang (possibly due to .Net application)

Tags: .net, windows-10, dump

I have a customer running my .Net Framework application on a couple hundred machines.  Randomly these machines will hang in the middle of the night - one hangs every few days.  The machines are completely unresponsive, so the customer is unable to access the machines to get any kind of a specific task dump.  The application and system event logs show no errors, but we do see our "heartbeat" event log message stop in the middle of the night.

The machines are so completely locked up we cannot get a task dump or even see what processes are running - we also tried attaching to it remotely.  No luck.

We are able to get a kernel dump by fording a system crash and dump through the keyboard.

So now I have a kernel dump of a hanged computer.  I know a little bit of WinDBG, using it to diagnose crashes and hangs with .Net applications.

I am looking for tips and suggestions to analyze a windows 10 Kernel dump to figure out why the machine has hanged.

thanks for your help.

Comment: "I am looking for tips and suggestions to analyze a windows 10 Kernel dump to figure out why the machine has hanged." Google is your friend.

Comment: 99.9% this is nothing to do with .NET, and everything to do with hardware or the OS. A stop_code at the very least would help us, plus the name of the faulting module, you can get this in WinDbg. Are you running any unusual hardware or software? What antivirus? Do all of the following: full Windows updates, all driver updates, `chkdsk` and memory diagnostic. Check also SMART params with CrystalDiskInfo or similar.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the tips.  As I mentioned this is a hang and the crash dump was manually initiated, so there is no stop code or faulting module.  I will get a list of all the hardware, software, updates etc.  This is happening on hundreds of machines, so I dont think specific machine diagnostics would be useful.

Comment: Then I suspect it's either a driver or software issue on identical machines. Try find what the common denominators are

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, here are some tips on how to analyze a kernel dump for a machine hang.

setup machine to force crashdump from keyboard:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard

In Windbg

- show deadlocked kernel threads: !locks
- For each of these threads show their owning processes and call stack: !thread {thread-id}
- Look at the process call stack to get a rough idea what the process was doing
- One or more of these process *may* be the process that is locking the computer.
- FWIW to get a list of all processes enter: !process

NOTE: kernel debugging is real memory, not virtual memory, so:

- in you cannot show .Net callstack for specific process
- you cannot show .Net deadlocked threads